# Linux: process of a bash shell launched by crontab still running after the shell is terminated

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, cron

There is an issue I would like to solve: I'm going to deploy on a Linux Red Hat 5 production environment (called PENV) a php web application under apache server; I am developing such this application on a development environment (called DENV) with Linux Mint 20.3.

On DENV, I created a crontab for the user *www-data* containing the following scheduled command:

```
0 4,12 * * * sh /bdir/s_etlShell.sh >/dev/null 2>&1;
```

the shell */bdir/s_etlShell.sh* starts everyday at 4.00 AM and at noon, and its execution lasts between 2 and 10 minutes. It also writes to a logfile */bdir/logshell.txt*.

the last two instructions of the shell are

```
echo "SHELL TERMINATED" >> /bdir/logshell.txt
exit
```

Past the 4.00 AM and noon, I found *SHELL TERMINATED* as a final statement inside /bdir/logshell.txt, but when I give the following command by terminal

```
ps fax | grep "s_etlShell.sh" | grep -v grep
```

I get the following output (the PID's are varying obviously):

```
ps fax | grep "s_etlShell.sh" | grep -v grep
   1596 ?        Ss     0:00      \_ /bin/sh -c sh /bdir/s_etlShell.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
   1605 ?        S      0:00          \_ sh /bdir/s_etlShell.sh
```

the processes of the shell look as if they were still active despite the shell terminated. I would expect no output instead.

I need to check the status of the shell execution in the web application via php script (*check_etl_shell_status.php*) launched every 2 seconds by the following javascript funcion

```
function loadCall() {

  setInterval(function () {$("#id_content").load("check_etl_shell_status.php",'q='); }, 2000);
}
```

the function *loadCall()* is being called on load the home page.

The content of *check_etl_shell_status.php* is the following

```
<?php

  $output = shell_exec('ps fax | grep "s_etlShell.sh" | grep -v grep');

  if ($output) {
    echo "shell is still running..."; 
  } else {
    echo "shell terminated";
  }
  
?>
```

and the output message is displayed inside a div of the home page

```
...
<div id="id_content"></div>
...
```

is there a way to make sure that, when a shell has terminated, whether is launched by crontab or on demand by web application, I have the right information on its status?

Thanks to whoever can help me

Comment: Whatever reason that makes you think you still need to be using RHEL5 is wrong.

Comment: unfortunately I have no jurisdiction on the PENV server, so it's no up to me to change the version